# Maven test classloader doesn't include target/classes folder

Tags: java, maven, java-module

I have a Maven project built on JDK 11, making full use of the Java Module System.

My problem is that I'd like to use Spring Data JPA repositories in my tests, but the Jpa Bean factory can't find my repository interfaces.

After some digging, I found that the reason is the classloader that Spring is trying to use to find the repository interfaces doesn't include the folder where the compiled main class files are saved, `target/classes`. Despite the fact that the [Maven surefire documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html) says that the directory should be included as the 2nd highest priority.

To better describe the issue, I created a demo [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rolaca11/test-classpath-demo), where I demonstrate my problem.

Without the `module-info.java` everything seems to work fine.

Comment: If you are using with the module system the directory is not the problem you have to open the package which is accessed... (Module-info: open ? If I correctly remember) cause it's access via reflection..from spring..(Is this Spring or a Spring Boot?)

Comment: if you have a look at the project I linked, you can see that the whole module is open. the module declaration starts with `open module <module_name>`

Comment: Also, I looked at the classloader fields with a debugger and saw that in the classpath list there was no `../target/classes` row, only when I removed the `module-info.java`. The most interesting part is not the there is no `classes` row in the classpath, but that there are 2 `test-classes` rows printed by the test method in the demo project

Comment: Without `module-info.java` both paths end with `/demo`, no trailing slash. With `module-info.java`, one element is `.../target/test-classes/demo` and the other `.../target/test-classes/demo/` (trailing slash).